# My animation doesn't render, gives as message "No frames rendered, skipped to not overwrite"

Tags: animation, camera, keyframes

i am using blender 2.81a. I have a 240 frame camera animation, and for some reason when I press ctrl f12, it skims through those 240 frames in 2 seconds and gives a message:

"No frames rendered, skipped to not overwrite"

What could it mean?

[image: m]

Comment: Seems like you already has rendered sequence and disabled *Overwrite* option in render settings. Check output folder.

Comment: Yes, I somehow forgot to change the output folder. It did not want to render on previous rendered frames. Thank you a lot!